# fire event when losing focus on bootstrap-modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap modal which I create with the data-tags so no actual javascript.
When I click outside the modal dialog (so on the grey area) it closes, but I want to make sure the fields that are in it are cleared.
I tried it with jQuery like so:

```
$('#modal-form > .modal-dialog').on('blur', function(){
    Utils.clearFields();
});
```

But I never come in the anonymous function, am I binding the wrong event? Or am I using the wrong selector (I also tried it with "$('#modal-form')")?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Version 2.3.2 and below

The event handler needs to be placed on `hide` for version Bootstrap version 2.3.2 and lower

```
$('#modal-form > .modal-dialog').on('hide', function(){
    Utils.clearFields();
});
```

If `#modal-form` has the modal data attributes applied the selector needs modified too:

```
$('#modal-form').on('hide', function(){
    Utils.clearFields();
});
```

**Documentation** http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

---

### Version 3.0

The event handler needs to be placed on `hide.bs.modal` for version Bootstrap version 3.0:

```
$("#modal-form").on("hide.bs.modal", function(){
   alert("hiding");
});
```

**Version 3.0 Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9u5MQ/

**Version 3.0 Documentation:** http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that I was using bootstrap3, however you pointed me to the right direction but just in case anyone else reads this I'm adding the bootstrap 3 code.

    $('#modal-form').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    Utils.clearFields();
});

and the link to the bootstrap3 documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals